# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar la variable iteradora de un bucle for para conformar una función?

Tags: python, lista, funciones, bucle-for

necesito buscar un dato dentro de una lista que contiene listas, y cuando la encuentre saber a que nombre de lista corresponde, además saber su numero de posición en la lista y sumarle `1` (solo necesito el valor numérico).

Logre realizar lo siguiente, pero no logro poder ver la posición del dato utilizando la variable iteradora `i` del bucle para aplicar la función `index` sobre la lista que corresponde.

Ejemplo del problema:

```
Box_1 = ['CFPU-0' , 'CSPU-0','USPU-0','EIPU-0', 'CSPU-2','USPU-2','USPU-4','EIPU-2']
Box_2 = ['CFPU-1' , 'CSPU-1','USPU-1','EIPU-1', 'CSPU-3','USPU-3','USPU-5','EIPU-3']
Box_3 = ['CFPU-4' , 'CSPU-6','USPU-8','EIPU-4', 'CSPU-10','USPU-12','USPU-6','EIPU-6']
Box_4 = ['CFPU-5' , 'CSPU-7','USPU-9','EIPU-5', 'CSPU-11','USPU-13','USPU-14','EIPU-7']
Box_5 = ['CFPU-7' , 'CSPU-15','USPU-17','EIPU-8', 'CSPU-19','USPU-21','USPU-9','EIPU-10']
Box_6 = ['CFPU-8' , 'CSPU-16','USPU-18','EIPU-9', 'CSPU-20','USPU-22','USPU-23','EIPU-11']
Box_7 = ['CFPU-10' , 'CSPU-24','USPU-26','EIPU-12', 'CSPU-28','USPU-30','USPU-32','EIPU-14']
Box_8 = ['CFPU-11' , 'CSPU-25','USPU-27','EIPU-13', 'CSPU-29','USPU-31','USPU-33','EIPU-15']

device= 'EIPU-8' # ejemplo de dato buscado

listas = [Box_1,Box_2,Box_3,Box_4,Box_5,Box_6,Box_7,Box_8]
for i, lista in enumerate(listas, start=1):
  for o in lista: # busco dentro de cada lista
    if o == device:
        print(f"Box_{i}: {o}") # me muestra OK  -> Box_5: EIPU-8  
        break

print(Box_5.index('EIPU-8')+1) # pero me falta poder descubrir esto que seria posición 3 y le sumo 1 => 4
```

Hay forma de poder ocupar la variable iteradora `i` / `o` del bucle para formar una función por ejemplo -> `Box_{i}.index({o})`.

¿Existe algo similar para poder aplicar esto?

¿Cómo puedo utilizar la variable `i` para realizar esto que busco?

Desde ya muchas gracias, saludos...

Comment: Por favor, no pongas lenguajes o similares como parte del título (a menos que realmente formen parte del texto de manera natural. En mi edición, quité la palabra _Python_ ya que en StackOverflow usamos etiquetas para clasificar las preguntas, y no los títulos.

Comment: Perfecto gracias por la aclaración...

Comment: Cuando tienes una serie de variables de igual nombre pero con un sufijo numérico como `Box_1`, `Box_2`, `Box_3`, etc.. lo que claramente necesitas  es repensar el programa. En lugar de 8 variables, ten una sola, `Box` que sea una lista. Y entonces `Box[0]` te dará el primer elemento (lo que equivaldría a tu variable `Box_1`), `Box[1]` te daría el siguiente, etc. En tu caso cada contenido de `Box` sería otra lista pero no pasa nada ¡puedes poner listas dentro de listas!

Comment: ok ahora entiendo el concepto no lo estaba viendo/entendiendo como tratar estos casos... muchas  gracias @abulafia .. saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes valerte justamente del método `index()` para saber cuál es el índice de un elemento en la lista.

Basado en el código de tu pregunta, preparé el siguiente ciclo:

```
for i, lista in enumerate(listas, start=1):
  for o in lista: # busco dentro de cada lista
    if o == device:
        print(f"Box_{i}: {o}") # me muestra OK  -> Box_5: EIPU-8  
        posicion = lista.index(device)
        print(f"Box_{i}[{posicion}]: {o}")
        print(posicion+1)
        break
```

Para averiguar el índice, también pude poner `lista.index(o)`, que tiene el mismo valor justo en esa iteracion, por lo que daría el mismo resultado.

Comment: genial me sirvió, muchas gracias @ jachguate